# Who gave Vajra or thunderbolt to Indra - Dadhichi or Usana?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, indra, weapon

In puranas [Dadhichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadhichi) is primarily known for sacrificing his life so the Devas, or benevolent celestial beings, could make the weapon called **"Vajra"** from his bones. After being driven out from Svarga, or heaven, by the serpent king Vritra, the Devas needed a powerful weapon to aid their fight. By making use of the Vajra, made from the sage Dadhichi's bones, the Devas defeated the Asura and reclaimed heaven.

---

However, Rig Veda tells a different story.

Usana is said to have increased the vigour of Indra ( RV. 1-51-10)

> The might which **Usana hath formed for thee with might rends in its  greatness** and with strength both worlds apart. O Hero-souled, the steeds of Vata, yoked by thought, have carried thee to fame while thou art filled with power.

Usana fashioned the thunderbolt for him for slaying Vritra

> Mount Indra, lover of the men thou guardest, the well-yoked horses of the wind, best bearers. The **bolt which Kavya Usana erst gave thee**, strong, gladdening, Vrtra-slaying, hath he fashioned.
>
> Rig Veda 1.121.12
>
> He who filled full his belly with the Soma's juice, Maghavan, was delighted with the meath's sweet draught, When **Usana, that he might slay the monstrous beast, gave him the mighty weapon with a thousand points**.
>
> Rig Veda 5.34.2

My question is this - Is it Usana, but not Dadhichi, in Rig Veda gave Indra the Vajra?